# Why are Golang http arguments (URL.Query()) map of lists?

Tags: go

When we call

```
r.URL.Query()
```

Inside a http route handler handler in Go, it returns a map[string][]string. I am wondering why is it a list and if I can use this property somehow when sending requests.

Comment: Use that property by using [`Values.Add`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values.Add)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a list because it is allowed to send multiple copies of the same query string parameter in a URL, and yes, you can send query string parameters in requests.

E.g. for a URL like `http://example.com/?foo=1&foo=2`, `Query()` would return:

```
{"foo": ["1","2"]}
```